# Filtering out anything older than a year before the MAX() date of grouped rows

Tags: mysql, database

I'd begun posting something about this a few days ago when I thought I may've found a good solution thanks to reading a few of the suggested posts. Unfortunately we found out today that there are some data gaps. As far as I can tell it's owing to the query.

I'm attempting to grab up a year's worth of spend data for items. If they were purchased multiple times throughout the year then I group on them and `SUM()` their quantities. The idea is to get a single row with all the needed info instead of 2, 10, or 100 based on each and every transaction that occurred.

The catch is that I don't want only a year's worth of data from today. I want year's worth that ends in the `MAX(date)` for that company's batch of spend. In other words, maybe a product was last purchased 3 months ago, but their last known transaction/PO was from only 1 month ago. The dates related to our data then should be everything from *1 year prior to 1 month ago*

Here is what I've currently got:

```
SELECT id, groupId, datePurchase, vendor, venItem, item, itemDesc, uom, SUM(qtyPurchase) AS `qtyPurchase`, SUM(extPrice) AS `totalPrice`, MAX(unitPrice) AS `maxPrice`, unitPrice, code, stripped_venitem, MAX(datePurchase) as `maxDate`, SUM(extPrice) as `extPrice`, PONum
FROM transactions t
WHERE (((qtyPurchase)!=0))
GROUP BY groupId, vendor, venItem, item, itemDesc, uom
HAVING datePurchase > (MAX(datePurchase) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

If I remove the `HAVING` portion then the data in question shows up. It's not that it's date is less than the prescribed year, though. When I remove the `HAVING` clause and find the product we're having a problem with, the `maxDate` value is "2015-08-26"

This is all part of an import to Solr so I need to get it right within a single query, no extra tricks or processing. Thanks for any insight!

---

EDIT 1:
It's worth noting, too, that I cannot have the `HAVING datePurchase > (MAX(datePurchase) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` portion migrated to part of the `WHERE` clause. If injected directly it throws an error of `invalid use of group function` and if it is added as a subquery (`...AND datePurchase > (SELECT MAX(datePurchase)...`) then it uses the value of `MAX(datePurchase)` corresponding to the *entire* dataset, not the particular groupId's that it should be related to.

That is worth stressing as well: the max date should be related to each particular entity's (listed as `groupId`) batch of transactions, not the entire table.

Comment: Don't you get an error for "desc" not enclosed in backticks? If the max date should be related to each particular entity, then you should only `GROUP BY groupId`. Why are there so many column names in the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I would, yes, but don't bc it was a mod that I made when writing it out on here, so a non-issue in the actual query. I can't group by the `groupId` alone bc the idea is to 'roll up' the same item. If they bought 2 foobars in January, 5 in May, and 4 last month then I want to have a single line representing the foobar purchase, showing a quantity of 11. Further, the products being truly the same require all of those `GROUP BY` fields to match. If it is foobar from ABC Co. and foobar from XYZ Co. then it is not considered to be the same. The same applies to its description and unit of measure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it was an arithmetic meets dates issue. I changed the `HAVING datePurchase > (MAX(datePurchase) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` to be `HAVING datePurchase > (MAX(datePurchase) - DATE_SUB(MAX(datePurchase), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))` and voila!